# What's The Difference Between Rate-Limiting and Throttling?

Tags: networking, reverse-proxy, rate-limiting

I keep hearing the terms used interchangeably, but is there an actual difference?
In [this](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/throttling-rate-limit-concept#:%7E:text=Rate%20Limiting%20and%20Throttling%20policies%20are%20designed%20to%20limit%20API,by%20smoothing%20spikes%20in%20traffic.) article they mention:

> Rate Limiting and Throttling policies are designed to limit API
> access, but have different intentions: Rate limiting protects an API
> by applying a hard limit on its access. Throttling shapes API access
> by smoothing spikes in traffic.

But it's kind of a vague definition, and doesn't specifically provide information about the actual differences.